# Master-slave + master-master replication at the same time

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave-replication, master-master-replication

Can a MySQL database which is doing master-slave replication to a number of slaves be configured to do master-master replication to a new server at the same time?

I have an application that has a main database (master1) and a number of front-end servers, each with a local slave database (slave1...n). These are doing filtered replication, filtering on *slave* with `replicate-do-db` and `replicate-wild-ignore-table`.

I'm trying to find a way to upgrade the master database without downtime. I need you to review and possibly confirm that the following would work.

1. Configure new server (master2) and import data from master1.
2. Turn on master-master replication so master2 replicates *everything* from master1
3. On each front-end server, change master to master2
4. Switch DNS record for main database from master1 to master2
5. Take down master1

Is this possible? Is there anything I should be paying attention to?

Comment: Please edit your question to use "server" for a piece of hardware that is running MySQL.  Keep "database" for a collection of data within such a server.  I think you are confusing "server" and "database".

Comment: Probably the answer is 'yes', but I want you to clarify -- in case you are talking about filtering replication at the database level via `binlog/replicate_do/ignore_db`.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks, updated question. No `binlog_*` configuration is used.